# How to delete multiple features from multiple layers in QGIS at once?

Tags: features, remove, multiple

I want to delete multiple layers containing points, lines, polygons together.  According to my research, the tools in qgis can only delete features of the active layer together, is there a method or tool that can delete multiple features from different layers at once?[image]

Comment: How to decide which features to delete?

Comment: If the condition to remove the features is the same for all layers, you can use the graphic modeler.

Comment: I want to delete all selected features from different layers.

Comment: How are you selecting features from different layers without making them active one by one?  If you can do that, prior to doing the selection put them in edit mode instead of just active.  You can have multiple layers in edit mode.  I haven't tried them but there are plugins for operating on or selecting multiple layers.  Search on the words multiple layer.

Comment: With the Multiple Layer Selection plugin
     It is possible to select several layers, but they cannot be deleted together because in QGis only one layer can be edited and deleted, and that layer is active.  It is not possible to delete two or more layers at the same time.  I checked all the features of the software but did not find anything.  Please introduce if you know a plugin to remove the selected features at the same time